# chage speed of text in textilate,js http://jschr.github.io/textillate/

Tags: javascript, word-automation

I am new to textilate.js (http://jschr.github.io/textillate/) does anyone know how to increase the spped of animation on textilate.js  Please help me out....

Answer (score 1):

Use the delayScale option.

So it would look something like this:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('ElementName').textillate({ in : {
            effect: 'rollIn',
             delayScale: .5,
        },
        out: {
            effect: 'hinge'
        },
        loop: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Textillate.js uses animate.css so if your effect happens to be *fadeInUp*, find the class *.fadeInUp* inside animate.css and add the following:

```
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
animation-duration: 1s;
```

You can tweak the duration from 1s to say 0.5s to make it even faster.